# import config variables from file in parent folder with python

Tags: python

I have the following file structure:

```
configs.py
__init__.py
(folder) /scritps
             load.py
```

I need to import in load.py a series of config values from configs.py

In `__init__.py` I have this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
__all__= ["configs"]
```

in load.py I import the file with this:

```
from .. import configs
```

but I always get this error:

```
from .. import configs
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I've also tried import the file using:

```
from ..configs import *
```

but I get the same error.

What I'm doing wrong?
I'm using python 2.6

Comment: `load.py` is not part of a package.  The `from .. import` syntax is for package-internal relative imports.  Since your file isn't part of a package in the first place, you get the error you see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you ensure your folder is in your PYTHONPATH. http://users-cs.au.dk/chili/PBI/pythonpath.html